# Linux kernel compile error Unsupported NR_CPUS for lb tracepoint

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile linux kernel 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, but I am getting an error:

```
In file included from kernel/fork.c:79:0:
include/trace/events/sched.h:249:2: error: #error "Unsupported NR_CPUS for lb tracepoint."
 #error "Unsupported NR_CPUS for lb tracepoint."
  ^
scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'kernel/fork.o' failed
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This forum post entitled ["Linux 3.4.0 : recipe for target 'kernel/fork.o' failed"](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/linux-3-4-0-recipe-for-target-%27kernel-fork-o%27-failed-4175635156/), shows how this issue was solved in the past:

> `NR_CPUS` is most probably the number of CPUs, and probably you need to set it (configure it), because the current value is unsupported.

**Try removing the `-j` option from the command to make the kernel if you have that set.**

Hope it helps.